# How to add a svg-object (created with DOMParser from a string) into a div element?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, innerhtml, standards-compliance

I have Firefox 41 running here.

I have a full svg file's code taken just randomly from commons at wikimedia.
(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/%2212_World_fly.svg)

Then I tried the following two versions to push it into an div-element, once using the div's innerHTML, once by trying the div's appendChild.

innerHTML worked at least, though looking at the generated html with webdeveloper looked a bit suspicious with the lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

also showing up.

Using appendChild didn't work at all.

I want to use something like appendChild, because I *know* there could be pitfalls when using innerHTML's parser.

**So, how to get the svg file's full string into the div?**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
 function dgebi(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
// short svg file as string
var svgtext = ... //... here I added the string from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/%2212_World_fly.svg
var d;
function init() {
    d = dgebi('id:testdiv');
    //useInnerHTMLToCreateSVG();
    useDOMParser();
}
function useInnerHTMLToCreateSVG() {
    d.innerHTML = svgtext;
}
function useDOMParser() {
// see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_an_SVG_or_HTML_document
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(svgtext, "image/svg+xml");
    // returns a SVGDocument, which also is a Document.
    d.appendChild(doc);
}    
function createElementSVG() {
    var se = document.createElement('SVG');
    d.appendChild(se);
    console.log(se);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<div style="width:400px;height:400px;border: 1px #ff0000 solid;" id="id:testdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append an element not a document i.e.

```
d.appendChild(document.adoptNode(doc.documentElement));
```

In practice you can leave out adoptNode. Though it is mandated by w3c (and noted by the8472 as being strictly correct) there are too many broken sites for browsers to enforce using it.

Also you can't create an SVG element with createElement (that will only create HTML elements). You need to use createElementNS i.e.

```
var se = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
```

note the lower case name because SVG is case sensitive.

Comment: This already works! Thank you! I saw this createElementNS, but I wondered why it needs an http-adress. Is there any risk that the browser would ever connect there? Or is it only this http-string as it is defined so? Because I want to make 100% sure the browser doesn't make a connection outside because of my code.

Comment: It's not a URL it's a namespace, it just looks like a URL. w3c could have have mandated you write bibblybobblyboo to identify SVG elements though you might have wondered what was in the water if they did.

Comment: great. So what did the createElement actually give me back? console.log shows an element with the nameSpaceURI "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"? Can I use this created Element in any way? Or should Firefox have shown an errormessage when trying to use createElement?

Comment: It gave you an html element with the name SVG. You could use it like any html element although it has no specific functionality.

Comment: transfering an element from one document to another should actually use [document.adoptNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode) first. Most browsers may be lenient about that, but not all are.

Comment: Is that crucial, for example for security reasons or for memory handling? I want to use the right form. (Especially as I will run this code on like 400.000 svg files, and I don't want to restart my browser every 1000 files.)

Comment: @John It has no effect on any current UA.

Comment: Without `adoptNode` It would simply fail on browsers that enforce the owner document rules of the DOM spec.

Comment: @the8472 except that there are no such browsers.

Comment: I wish I would know as much as you guys about this. :) Thank you all.

Comment: @RobertLongson, some older browser versions do. and so do some java and npm DOM implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Example of working code:

```
var renderRatingReviews = function (opts) {
    var options = opts || {},
        namespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
        svg = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'svg'),
        circle = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'circle'),
        arc = document.createElementNS(namespace, 'path'),
        text = document.createElement('div'),
        width = options.width || 100,
        height = options.height || 100,
        radius = width / 2,
        container = options.container,
        thickness = options.thickness || 9,
        color = options.color === 'green' ? '#00B930' : options.color === 'orange' ? '#fe9d14' : options.color === 'red' ? '#ff5534' : '#00B930',
        rating = options.rating || 8,
        polarToCartesian = function (centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
            var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;
            return {
                x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
                y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
            };
        },
        describeArc = function (x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
            var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle),
                end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle),
                arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1",
                d = [
                    "M", start.x, start.y,
                    "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
                ].join(" ");
            return d;
        },
        addSize = function (val) {
            return val;
        };
    if (container) {
        text.innerHTML = rating;
        text.className = 'text';
        svg.setAttribute('width', addSize(width));
        svg.setAttribute('height', addSize(height));
        circle.setAttribute('cy', addSize(height / 2));
        circle.setAttribute('cx', addSize(width / 2));
        circle.setAttribute('r', addSize(radius - (thickness / 2)));
        circle.setAttribute('stroke', '#e8e8e8');
        circle.setAttribute('stroke-width',  addSize(thickness));
        circle.setAttribute('fill', '#ffffff');
        arc.setAttribute('stroke', color);
        arc.setAttribute('stroke-width',  addSize(thickness));
        arc.setAttribute('fill', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
        arc.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');
        arc.setAttribute('d', describeArc(width / 2, height / 2, addSize(radius - (thickness / 2)), 0, 359 * rating / 10));
        svg.appendChild(circle);
        svg.appendChild(arc);
        container.appendChild(svg);
        container.appendChild(text);
    }
}

renderRatingReviews({
    container: document.getElementById('elementId')
});
```